# user Database design

Tags: database, database-design

I am creating a user account table that needs to store follwoing information

```
1. username
2.password
3. lastlogin date
4. account status
5.first name
6. last name
7. gender
8. zipcode
```

Question: Is it a good design/efficient to create separate table for useraccount and profile information(stores firstname, lastname,gender,zipcode) even though its a 1:1 reationship.
Basically is it a good practice to have logical separation for 1:1 relationship?

Thanks

Comment: no idea. depends entirely on your needs and any future plans you may have. e.g. what if you want to store historical copies of profiles? then it's not 1:1 anymore, it'll be 1:n.

Comment: **Rule of thumb:** 1 to 1 relationships are rare, and seldom required.  When they are, it's because you have some optional, but expensive data that you don't want in every primary record.